# If two matrices both multiplied by the same vector are equal are the matrices equal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Assume A and B are n x n matrices.

If Av$_k$ = Bv$_k$ then is A = B where v$_k$ is a vector in R$^n$?

Comment: If $Av=Bv$ for $n$ linearly independent vectors, then $A=B$. But otherwise no.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Can you explain why it is true for linearly independent vectors?

Comment: You should *really* try some easy examples before you ask, @n8sty. For example, $$\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\binom{1}{0}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\binom{1}{0}$$

Comment: I can't understand why in the comment above the LaTeX doesn't come up right if when I write that in an answer it appears fine!

Comment: If $Av_i=Bv_i$ for certain vectors $v$, it is true for any linear combination of the $v_i$. If we have $n$ linearly independent $v_i$, they form a basis, and thefore $Av=Bv$ for all $v$. In particular, $Aw=Bw$ for all vectors that form the standard basis $(1,0,0,\dots)$ and so on. But that means the columns of $A$ and $B$ are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Counterexample:
$A=\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right]$, $B=\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right]$, $v_k=(1,0)$.

Notice that for $w=(0,1)$ we have $Aw\neq Bw$.  This relates to what was mentioned in the comments: that equality must hold over every element of a basis to conclude that $A=B$.

Comment: If both A and B can be shown to be invertable then can A and B be said to be equal?

Comment: @AidanR.S. No, as the same example but with $B=\left[ \begin{array}{cc}1 &1\\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right]$ shows.  Either way we need to know the equality holds over a set of basis vectors (or any spanning set).