# What can be concluded about two matrices relating the same vectors (u=Mv, u=Nv)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

If we have two matrices $M,N$ that relate two non-zero vectors $u,v$ according to
$$\begin{align}
u &= Mv \\
u &= Nv 
\end{align}$$
what can be concluded about $M$ and $N$?

According to this question:
[If two matrices both multiplied by the same vector are equal are the matrices equal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/551110/if-two-matrices-both-multiplied-by-the-same-vector-are-equal-are-the-matrices-eq)
we unfortunately cannot conclude they are equal.

Can we conclude that their determinants are the same?
I do not think so, because maybe $\det(M)\ne 0,\det(N)=0$ with $v$ not in the null space of $N$.

But maybe we can say this weaker statement? The matrices are equal or at least one of the matrices has a determinant of zero.

Also, because $(M-N)v = 0$, it looks like we can at least conclude $v$ is in the null space of $(M-N)$.

Looking at the norm of $u$, we have:
$$u^T u = v^T M^T M v = v^T N^T N v = v^T M^T N v = v^T N^T M v.$$
Can we somehow use this to conclude something stronger about $M^T M, N^T N, M^T N, N^T M$ ?

It feels really surprising to me that we can conclude so little about $M$, $N$, from what appears to be a strong relationship. So I'm hoping there is something useful for linear equation solving that I'm missing.

Comment: Please, if you down vote, tell me why. I am new and do not know what you want me to fix.

Comment: I upvoted to cancel the unexplained downvote. "what appears to be a strong relationship": It's not a strong relationship; it's $2n$ equations for $2n^2$ unknowns.

Comment: It just says that there is one vector $v$ for which $(N-M)v = 0$. It is easy to check with say diagonal matrices that you can have this condition satisfied and choose $\det M, \det N$ arbitrarily. For a matrix to be zero, it must be zero when applied to a basis.

Comment: @joriki That is a good point, thank you. That makes it easy to see how far off my expectations were. More explicitly, choosing an orthonormal basis with one basis vector parallel to v, would mean one column of the matrices are equal in this basis, and no other constraints. A far cry from being able to say anything regarding the determinants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple counterexample: $$M = \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}, N=\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix} \\ M\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix} = N\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}.$$ You only have one pair of vectors providing a constraint, which doesn’t make for a particularly “strong” relationship, even in a two-dimensional space. In the above example, for instance, the second columns of both $M$ and $N$ can be anything, and you will still have $Mu=Nu=v$. With larger matrices, you will have even more degrees of freedom. The same goes for the various inner products that you’re examining: equality for only one specific pair of vectors doesn’t provide as much information as one might think.